# How to Declare mongo models from different files with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure in my Node.js TypeScript project:

[image]

The important part here is the mongoModels. I have 2 models and they are connected as each Category model has field category.expertUserIds which contains array of user._id.

user.ts:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
});

module.exports = model("User", userSchema);
```

category.ts:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  expertUserIds: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = model("Category", categorySchema);
```

I have many project on exactly the same concept created as regular .js files but when I use TypeScript it is giving me this error:

> mongoModels/category.ts:1:17 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare
> block-scoped variable 'model'.
>
> 1 const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
> ~~~~~

Same is for Schema and for both files. So basically it counts that I declared already:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
```

once and I cannot do it again for other file. How is that an error and how I can fix it as I am invoking Schema and model in different files?

Comment: Is your code public on GitHub? Would you mind posting a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found solution. It was to replace:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
```

with:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
```

I don't know why TS didn't worked with "require".

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript basically runs on ESM(ECMAScript module) for Node. So you need to use `import` in place of `const` and `require`. TypeScript supports the EcmaScript module syntax which means you will be using modules in TypeScript using `import` and `export` keywords which is very convenient.

You can only import files ending with `.ts` and `.d.ts` extensions (as well as `.js` file). When you import these files using the import statement, they become modules.